# OpenERP HR Attendance affect Table

Tags: postgresql, odoo

I want to know which table used to save records regarding the attendance and leaves in OpenERP ver 7.
I found that resource_resource table,res_users and hr_employee tables used to keep employee's records.but which one used to keep above records.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select
h.id as employee_id,h.name as leave_reason,
e.resource_id,e.name_related,s.name,r.id as resource,r.name as res_name
from 
hr_holidays h,hr_employee e,hr_holidays_status s,
resource_resource r
where 
h.employee_id=e.id and 
h.holiday_status_id=s.id and
e.resource_id=r.id
```